# error log cluttered with undefined DB_USER wp-admin/setup-config.php

Tags: wp-config

I have an up and running WordPress site for some time.

Lately, I noticed somebody or something is making requests to `www.example.com/wp-admin/setup-config.php?step=0`. Which is resulting in these entries in my error log?

```
PHP Warning:  Use of undefined constant DB_USER - assumed 'DB_USER' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in /var/www/html/wp-includes/load.php on line 404, referer: example.com/wp-admin/setup-config.php?step=0│
undefined constant DB_PASSWORD - assumed 'DB_PASSWORD' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in /var/www/html/wp-includes/load.php on line 404, referer: example.com-admin/setup-config.php?step=0
undefined constant DB_NAME - assumed 'DB_NAME' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in /var/www/html/wp-includes/load.php on line 404, referer: example.com/wp-admin/setup-config.php?step=0
undefined constant DB_HOST - assumed 'DB_HOST' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in /var/www/html/wp-includes/load.php on line 404, referer: example.com/wp-admin/setup-config.php?step=0
```

When I visit `www.example.com/wp-admin/setup-config.php?step=0` I see the above errors are added to the error.log and the normal message as expected in my browser:

> The file wp-config.php already exists. If you need to reset any of the
>   configuration items in this file, please delete it first. You may try
>   installing now.

The site is working properly. Of course, I do not want to run the config script. And `DB_USER`, `DB_PASSWORD`, `DB_NAME` and `DB_HOST` are defined my `wp-config.php` file.

**A** How can I prevent unwanted access to the setup-config.php file?
**B** If people are requesting setup-config.php. How do I prevent the error.log from being cluttered?

I do not want to disable logging warnings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place a `.htaccess` file in the folder `wp-admin` with the following content:

```
<Files "setup-config.php">
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
</Files>
```

Optionally you can add the line `Allow from {your ip address}` after `Deny from all`, so you can access the file.